# PHP Session Value not being passed

Tags: php, xml, session

I was able to successfully setup sessions and pass it to other pages, but only by hard coding the value or via POST, GET.

I'm working with a 3rd party vendor that sends xml data to my page, but for the life of me, cannot pass on session value that i set on page 1 to the next page.

**Here is an example of my code on the 1st page:**

```
session_start();

$data = $_POST['name'];
$decode = urldecode ($data);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($decode);

$username=$xml->PERSON[0]->USERID;
$email=$xml->PERSON[0]->EMAIL;

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

echo $_SESSION['username']; (correctly displays username)

header("Location: ./next-page.php");
```

**2nd page**

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

2nd page echo does not display username. 
It does display correctly if $username value is hardcoded on page 1 or if passed from say a login page using POST to page 1.

Comment: What happens on page 2 if you do `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Does your browser accept sessions? What browser?

Comment: can you paste example of $_post['name']?

Comment: If you use local server check disk space and permissions on folder with sessions

Comment: what is the output of `echo $x = session_start()` in the 2nd page?

Comment: According to PHP.net (http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) you might want to check your http domain. Try űini_set("session.cookie_domain",substr($_SERVER[HTTP_HOST],3));

Comment: @Hydra IO, array(4) { ["buildingName"]=> string(9) "xxxx" ["givenName"]=> string(5) "xxxx" ["sn"]=> string(4) "xxxx" ["usertype"]=> int(1) }

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan, 1

Comment: @AKHAN - ok, so what's the error you're getting?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link which fixed my issue.

http://www.ossramblings.com/simple_xml_breaks_sessions

It turns out that you can't take a response from a SimpleXML object and store it in a session. You'd think that if you could type "echo $myxml->thisnode" and get a string that it's really a string, but PHP automatically typecasts and converts as needed - except in the case of storing in a session variable.

There's an easy solution. Use explicit typecasting when trying to store an XML result string in a $_SESSION[] variable:

```
$_SESSION['myinteger'] = (int)$myxml->myinteger;
$_SESSION['mystring'] = (string)$myxml->mystring;
```

So in my case, on page 1:

```
session_start();

$data = $_POST['name'];
$decode = urldecode ($data);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($decode);

$username=$xml->PERSON[0]->USERID;
$email=$xml->PERSON[0]->EMAIL;

$_SESSION['username'] = ($string)$username;

header("Location: ./next-page.php");
```